# Servlet + URL

Tags: url, java, servlet, vaadin

Вообщем до конца не понятно с URL ссылками в Java Servlets.
Сделал сайт на Vaadin, но он получился как одно целое, или как одна программа.
Всё что есть, находится в корне (/) и соответственно скопировав ссылку попадаешь всегда в начало сайта.
Покопав по servlet, нашёл в web.xml, servlet-mapping => url-pattern.
Т.е. в java каждая страница это отдельный servlet ?

Comment: почитайте про post, get запросы

Comment: чем они могут помочь?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vaadin - это фреймворк, со своими приколами и идеями насчет веб приложений. Если кратко, то он скрывает в себя всю логику переадресаций, аджакс и тд, потому ты не видишь адреса страниц по отдельности, если хочешь играться с сервлетами - лучше пробуй без Vaadin-а, создай jsp и посмотри, как что и куда мапится.

Comment: здесь также vaadin, но есть поддержка ссылок
http://www.guimachine.ru
как они это сделали?

Comment: наверно и в обычном можно Vaadin можно включить отображение, я не знаю. Когда-то писал авторизацию для Vaadin средствами Spring Security, так Spring Security - сделал аутентифика́цию, а уже внутри Vaadin - авторизацию

Comment: Их ссылки не покидают пределов страницы. Например: http://www.guimachine.ru/#view/ALSFR-d6a8cd38-81cd-4c29-8067-a5c2b3a04efdforceShow. Как видите путь ссылки отбит символом `#`, то есть является на самом деле ссылкой внутри текущей страницы. Подробнее об этой технику можно почитать [на хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/113842/).

Answer (score 1):

Если вам еще надо,то:

В url-pattern вы должны указывать как вызвать ваш севлет по url.Например

```
 <url-pattern>/testform</url-pattern>
```

Тогда вызвать сервлет можно будет по url:

http://localhost:8080/Имявашегоприложения/testform

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, понял.
Есть [плагин](https://vaadin.com/ru/directory#addon/navigator7).
и этот (использую его) [плагин](http://code.google.com/p/nf4v/).